# What are some of the best non-english general programming resources?

Tags: resources, forums, non-english

It may be my own limited perspective, but it seems that a majority of computer programming websites and resources are English-only or English-mostly. Certainly the role of English in the development of programming languages has been a factor, as discussed in some [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202723/coding-in-other-spoken-languages) SO [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288061/do-there-exist-any-compilers-with-localized-versions-of-programming-languages).

So I'm curious, what are some of the important (well thought of, well trafficked, etc) programming websites/forums/resources/etc where the discussion is primarily in a language other than English?

Comment: should be community wiki

Answer (score 7):

[RSDN](http://www.rsdn.ru) is a well known Russian-language online resource.

Answer (score 1):

There are tons, but at the end most of them end referring to an english source, for the content ( computer programming  content that is ) is generated in english most of the times.

What's language are you interested in?

Google code website is offered in: 中文 - English - Português - Pусский - Español - 日本語

But again, the main content is generated in english.

Besides, english is not that hard after all ( although mastering english is,  as in  any other language )

Answer (score 1):

[SelfHTML](http://de.selfhtml.org/) is a pretty big and well-known German reference website about web techologies 
HTML, XHTML, CSS, XML/DTD,JavaScript/DOM, Perl, PHP and the like. It's been around for ages and there there is a lively community behind it constantly updating it and adding new content.

Answer (score 0):

I work with Spanish programming students. I find that searching for the phrase "programming terms" using the particular language in question uncovers many sites with translations of terms.

In Spanish "términos de programación" reveals many sites around the world that have taken the time to translate the terms. I'd do the translations myself, but not being a native speaker of Spanish would undermine the effort.

A good resource in Spanish: [Link](http://www.alegsa.com.ar/)