# How do programming languages differ between different parts of the world?

Tags: programming-languages, globalization

I have always wondered how programming languages are different, if they are indeed different, to other parts of the world? How do people in parts of Asia/Europe/South America use programming? Whats the syntax like? Any examples?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202723/coding-in-other-spoken-languages and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440052/should-identifiers-and-comments-be-always-in-english-or-in-the-native-language-of and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250824/do-you-use-another-language-instead-of-english and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653227/how-hard-would-it-be-to-translate-a-programming-language-to-another-human-languag

Comment: In general, no, they don't differ. A programming language is a language. It doesn't differ from country to country any more than Spanish or Japanese does. A C++ programmer writes in C++ regardless of where he lives. He doesn't write in Swedish or German or Mexian.

Comment: +1.. ok, feeling better now thanks

Comment: It's a general principle that you can write comments in most other languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good thing of programming languages is that they are almost universal (excluding some unicode support related things :D ).

I think that everywhere they're just the same, same syntax and same behaviour.. IT is based on standards, programming languages are not excluded!

Comment: thats very interesting! I remember way back when I had my hands on some code from another country and I can't remember where I put it, but this question cross my mind so i figured id ask

Comment: probably variables name were different, or class names, but the syntax is always the same.. of course it's possible to reinvent a language just translating keyword in other languages but why do you need to do it? English is so concise..

Answer (score 5):

There are indeed a small number of [non-English programming languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-English-based_programming_languages).  They do not enjoy widespread use.  In programming in particular, and slightly less with technology in general, English seems to be the language of choice.  I think this is likely due to the Internet originating in the US.

Comment: You know, when you look at it, most of the history of computing takes place in either the US or Britain, even going back to Charles Babbage.  IBM started with an invention meant to help the US census.  The US and Britain both worked on computers to crack German encryptions in WW II.  UNIX was developed in New Jersey.  And of course, many of the modern day computing giants are located in Silicon Valley.

Answer (score 3):

Here in Sweden (Northern Europe) I guess it's pretty much the same as in the USA.  Java, python, ruby, C#, C++, perl are all quite popular.  Functional languages as Lisp and Erlang (actually a language invented here in Sweden, and quite good for distributed stuff) are less common, but not all that uncommon.

Answer (score 3):

Basically we all have to learn English :)

Comment: are there non-english programming languages?

Comment: Only a few words, haha.  I imagine it would be weird, especially if you didn't know English.  I would have trouble at first programming in another language...

público estático vacío principal (Secuencia[] args) {
   // ¡Pero no hablo español!
}

Comment: @Kaleb: +1 for inventing Spanish Java

Comment: Ni me imagino, creando una clase sellada o retornando un nulo.

Comment: @Kaleb: in some cases, we have to learn much more. Java language has just a few words, but Java API has a lot. Not to mention the documentation...

Answer (score 3):

I used to make comments and variable/method names in spanish, then a teacher told me to write in english, despite my native language, if i wanted my code to be any worth, it had to be in english, for its the one language the whole programming community (or a really big majority) knows

Answer (score 2):

I m pretty sure that you can find people who write C/C++ , java , C#  code everywhere since almost all universities teach those language , the only difference is the naming of variables and functions (or methods) usualy they are named based on the native language of the developer

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that differs is what people name their variables, and what locale settings they use.

Comment: I name them in English even if I'm Italian ;-)