# how do I change a python interpreter from english to my dialect

Tags: python

I have been stuck for months trying to edit the python interpreter (from www.python.org). All I want to do is to change the keywords eg. change from. English language: print() to Ibo language de().

Comment: You cannot change Python's functions or keywords to another language.

Comment: First language you have to learn when learning how to program is english.

Comment: And what's more you shouldn't WANT to. If you're serious about programming, you NEED to have a very strong grasp of English. Everything from documentation to forums to keywords and built-ins are in English. There's no way around it.

Comment: well you "can" but then it wouldn't run the standard library without you changing it too to Ibo.

Comment: You can make an alias to functions with standard variable assignment but keywords like `and` `or` `if` `else` `pass` can't be changed. I suggest using regex to parse your own program with another program

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions in another script to parse your main script:

```
import re

old = open('main.py')
data = old.read()
old.close()

data = re.sub(r'\bde\b', 'print', data)
# continue to replace other keywords

new = open('main.py', 'w')
new.write(data)
new.close()
```