# Can I rename keywords in R?

Tags: r

I would like to achieve something like this:

```
se    <- .Primitive("if")
senao <- .Primitive("else") # I get an error here
para  <- .Primitive("if")

# The code I would like to run
se (1 == 1){
  # Some code
} senao {
  #more code
}

# This also doesn't work
para(1 in 1:3)
{
  print(i)
}
```

I would like to use the mechanism above to teach children who don't know how to speak English yet how to program. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can rename built-in *functions* e.g. `v <- c` allows for `v(4,5,6)`

Comment: Yes, I noticed that I can rename functions. However, if I can't rename all of the keywords I still have an issue :(

Comment: R only has about 5 such words, and they are very short. Would it really be that much of an obstacle even for a child?

Comment: Probably not, I'll give it a shot

Comment: If you are using RStudio, you could use Code Snippets with names like `senao`. See [this](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/204463668-Code-Snippets) for how to customize snippets. One of the built-in snippets allows `el` to be used for `else`. This seems like a lot of trouble for little gain, but might be useful to you.

Comment: Some relevant discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202723/coding-in-other-spoken-languages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. This is not possible in R. The parser has special cases for certain keywords. They cannot be changed (without altering the source code for R and compiling your own unique version).

Comment: Do you know whether I can do this in another high level language with simple syntax?

Comment: Maybe a language that uses macros like C or C++. But I am not an expert on all other high level languages.